# Tkinter Canvas Slow

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a moving bullet in Tkinter on a canvas. I delete it and redraw it every frame. The canvas still gets slow after only around 4/5 drawings. What am I missing?

```
class Bullet:
    def __init__(self,x,y,r,vx,vy):
        # realX/Y represent the real location of the bullet as a float
        self.realX = x
        self.realY = y
        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy
        self.r = r # Radius
        self.speed = 0.96 # Pixels per frame

def level1_loop():
    move_bullets()

    draw()
    window.after(1,level1_loop)

def move_bullets():
    global timer
    global canvas

    if time() > timer + 1:
        # Create a new bullet every second
        newbul = Bullet(rand(0,1920),0,20,0,0)
        diffX = window.winfo_pointerx() - newbul.realX
        diffY = window.winfo_pointery() - newbul.realY
        scale = newbul.speed / (diffX ** 2 + diffY ** 2) ** 0.5
        newbul.vx = diffX*scale
        newbul.vy = diffY*scale
        bullets.append(newbul)
        timer = time()

    for bullet in bullets:
        # Update bullet position
        bullet.realX += bullet.vx
        bullet.realY += bullet.vy

def draw():
    global canvas
    canvas.delete('bullet')
    for bullet in bullets:
        canvas.create_oval(bullet.realX-bullet.r,bullet.realY-bullet.r,bullet.realX+bullet.r,bullet.realY+bullet.r,tag="bullet")
        if bullet.realX > 1920 or bullet.realY > 1080:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is slow specifically because you are deleting and redrawing the bullets. Instead of that, you should be moving the existing bullets rather than redrawing them. The canvas has known performance problems when you create lots of canvas items, even if you delete the canvas items. Canvas item ids are not recycled, so the list of item ids that the canvas must maintain grows without bounds and makes the canvas slower on each iteration.

It's also slow because you are trying to redraw 1000 times per second even though your eye can't perceive anything close to th at. You are wasting a lot of cpu cycles doing something which you cannot perceive.

Here is similar advice from someone who has worked on the underlying Canvas implementation: [Tkinter GUI app runs slower as time goes on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786627/tkinter-gui-app-runs-slower-as-time-goes-on/34412732#34412732)